# Can a notification to the status bar be called from an asynctask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am new to Android programming and not very experienced in Java.

I am loading a url with a webview in an activity, then calling an asynctask to parse text from a url. After parsing I would like to post this to the status bar with a notification. After doInBackground I am passing the parsed string to `onPostExecute` but have compiler errors.

1. Not sure if I can call a notificationcompat.builder from
   onPostExecute in asynctask or if it needs to be called from an
   activity.
2. Will onPostExecute automatically get called after doInBackground?

Thanks, Craig

```
protected void onPostExecute(String mycontent) {
// set up for notification in the notification status bar
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())

.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notify_lightning)
                        .setContentTitle("My Title Here")
                        .setContentText(mycontent);


        // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, WebViewActivity.class);

// The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
// started Activity.
// This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
// your application to the Home screen.
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
// Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(WebViewActivity.class);
// Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                        0,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        // Sets an ID for the notification
        int mNotificationId = 001;
// Gets an instance of the NotificationManager service
        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// Builds the notification and issues it.
        mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onPostExecute` will be called automatically on main thread after `doInBackground`, can u tell more details of compiler errors?

Comment: getApplicationContext() - Cannot resolve method (this used to be 'this')

Comment: I'm not sure the best way to put in the lines that are in error.  Most of the errors seem to stem from the Context (this) which I really don't understand. Also, not sure what you mean by main thread.  WebViewActivity is the main activity in the manifest and I call (another class) my asynctask from there: _myasynctask.execute();  doInBackground

Comment: try use `WebViewActivity.this.getApplicationContext()`

Comment: As a follow on, I would like to use NotificationCompat to send a notification via Alarmmanager and BroadcastReceiver as a separate task not on the main activity.  The notification contains information retrieved at specified intervals from a webpage.  What can I use to do this network operation in the BroadcastReceiver as AsyncTask wants to be called on the main activity.  I've searched here but haven't found a solution.  If I should put this as a new question, please let me know.  Thanks.